# MySQL: replicate some tables with replicate-ignore-db and binlog-ignore-db

Tags: mysql, replication

Is there any way to replicate some tables from `db1` and `db2` with these settings:

```
replicate-ignore-db=db1
replicate-ignore-db=db2
binlog-ignore-db=db1
binlog-ignore-db=db2
```

There are other databases that need to be replicated so I can't use `replicate-wild-do-table` instead.

Comment: which version you are using? those options are available in replication from >MySQL 5.6, actually binlog_do_db is available so you can mention only the wanted ones there and for others binlogs would not be generated

Comment: `MySQL 5.1` I'm afraid